# Assert each flag in rest assured array is equal to True/False

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have response that is a list of buildings, each of these buildings have a flag which is either true or false.

How could I iterate through this response and assert that every one of these flags is equal to true or false?

```
jsonPath =new JsonPath(response.body().asString());
List<String> interventionAreas = jsonPath.getList("locations.interventionArea");
```

I feel like I am over complicating things by doing it like this. Is there a way with restassured to assert for each element with "interventionArea"